# What does single user mode in Linux/Unix means and how is it different from Safe mode in Windows

Tags: linux, security, sudo, safe-mode

What is Single User mode used for? Can it override the root Password? Do you need a password to acces the SU mode?

In a normal session when you run SU command does it stands for Single User or Super User?

Comment: `su` means switch user, not superuser.  The command for running something as superuser is `sudo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single user mode and `su` aren't exactly the same, if you're referring to the boot option `single`.

Single user mode ([from adding `single` to grub's boot commands](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132965/how-do-i-boot-into-single-user-mode-from-grub) or [add init="/bin/bash" to the kernel line](https://www.vultr.com/docs/boot-into-single-user-mode-reset-root-password)) should basically let you log in with root access & change just about anything. Basically:

> your computer boots to runlevel 1. Your local file systems are mounted, but your network is not activated. You have a usable system maintenance shell. Unlike rescue mode, single-user mode automatically tries to mount your file system; do not use single-user mode if your file system can not be mounted successfully. You can not use single-user mode if the runlevel 1 configuration on your system is corrupted.

(from [Red Hat docs](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/3/html/System_Administration_Guide/s1-rescuemode-booting-single.html))

---

`su` looks like it *could* stand for super user... but I'm not holding my breath on finding reliable definitive info on the origin of `su`'s name. Probably like other "old school" unix/linux names, it could be shorthand for something, or just for fun, self-referencing acronym, a couple's names or initials (debian), just about anything really.

According to the (sometimes?) reliable [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Su_%28Unix%29):

> The Unix command su, also referred to as substitute user, super user, or switch user, is used by a computer user to execute commands with the privileges of another user account. When executed it invokes a shell without changing the current working directory or the user environment.
>
> When the command is used without specifying the new user id as a command line argument, it defaults to using the superuser account (user id 0) of the system.

Also interesting on `sudo`:

> The command sudo is related, and executes a command as another user but observes a set of constraints about which users can execute which commands as which other users. Unlike su, sudo authenticates users against their own password rather than that of the target user